# Enumeration in the dialog box

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

My tableViewController with a list of items of various types will provide a button to show a modal dialog box. This dialog box (similar to alert view)  will provide the user with an exclusive choice from a list of 6 options.
Based on what the user chooses and confirms, the list in the main tableview controller screen will be filtered down to only show items that match the selected type. 
At the moment, I have those six types listed in a typedefed enum. So far so good.
However I also need to be able to populate my custom dialog box with six nsstrings whose names will match the types used in the enumeration.
How to reconciliate this enum with my requirement for a source of those strings, but in such a way that I would ensure some level of consistency between the two? I do not want to hardcode anything.

Comment: Instead of `typedef enum` why don't you just store an array of NSStrings and compare the two?

Comment: I can't get rid of that enumeration, it is used elsewhere in the app, its a quite complex project. The problem is obviously that enumerations do not provide a way to get enum names, they are just fancy ints.

Comment: @mkral Such a solution doesn't handle localization very well. Labels should be just that - labels. The enum represents the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a helper method that returns a string for each enum value. This should be written to deal with possible localization. All of your data and event handling should be based on the enum value. The string should be used for display.

The helper method should take an enum value and use a switch statement to return the proper string.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few:

- Change the enum to a bunch of strings. This makes things a bit tedious if they need to be integers too (`-[NSArray indexOfObject:]`).
- Make a C array of strings. This lets you use C99's handy syntax:

  ```
  NSString * const names[] = {
    [Foo] = @"Foo",
    [Bar] = @"Bar",
  };
  ```
- Autogenerated code to do the above.

Caveats:

- Both of these will make i18n rather painful. This might not be relevant if it's contract work that will only need to be in one language, but it's Bad Practice.
- Using button indexes as keys works until you decide you need to remove buttons in the middle. String keys work much better in the general case (I wrote a UIAlertView/UIActionSheet wrapper that accept (key,title) pairs and returned the key instead of the button index).

Answer (score 1):

I take your remark that you "do not want to hardcode anything" to mean that you don't want any string constants in your code. So:

You could simply assign the strings to your sheet's UI elements (perhaps check boxes, for example) and give those UI elements tag values that match your enumeration (something you could query as your sheet closes). This has the additional benefit that you can easily localize the sheet.

Or:

If you want to keep the strings separate from your sheet, you could create a .strings file (perhaps you could call it Enumeration.strings or some such) formatted something like this:

```
"001" = "string one";
"002" = "string two";
.
.
"010" = "string ten";
```

and you could then retrieve the strings using your enumeration values like this:

```
NSString *myString = NSLocalizedStringFromTable([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03d", myEnumerationValue], @"Enumeration", @"");
```

but then you'd have to have a way of plugging the strings into your UI, keeping track of UI elements through `IBOutlet`s. Note that I used three decimal places here; perhaps you could get by with two, or even one. Finally, you get the ability to localize as in the first suggestion.